# Top row of keyboard (volume etc.) have started doing different things

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, dell

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell XPS15 9500. A few days ago, the buttons on the top row of my keyboard stopped working properly. They seem to be assigned to different things. For example the mute button launches a help page.

I haven't changed my keyboard settings, and if I look at the keyboard setting, `launch help browser` is disabled for example. But volume up, volume down, brightness up, brightness down etc. are all doing different things.

Comment: You probably pressed Fn Lock button. Press it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top row of this laptop doubles as function keys and media keys. By default, the media keys are in effect, and one has to hold down <kbd>Fn</kbd> to access the function keys. You can hit <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to change the behaviour - hitting "Mute" will then act as <kbd>F1</kbd> (which is what you currently have) and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> will act as the mute key.

If the change is not remembered between reboots, then you can still change how these keys behave after startup in the computer's Bios settings.

Comment: It seems like the issue is that media keys are doing *different* media tasks than they did originally, not that they are acting as media keys rather than function keys.